# Only sprites can be added to a group although it's a sprite

Tags: sprite, p5.js

I'm trying to make a sketch in which a sprite animation appears when I click on another sprite. It appears on the middle of the screen and it should be able to be pushed by the mouse which also has a sprite attached to it.

As soon as I want to add the appearing-onMousePressed sprites to a group or to the mouseBlock.displace(), I get an error saying "Uncaught Error: overlap can only be checked between sprites or groups". I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is it because the sprites are created through a function? Or is my order of things wrong? Please help me.

```
var movingBlocks;
var mouseBlock;
var bb1;
var b1;

function preload() {
  mouseBlock = loadImage('mouse.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  mouseBlock = createSprite(200,200);
  mouseBlock.addAnimation('normal', 'mouse.png');

  movingBlocks = new Group()
  var b1 = createSprite(windowWidth-200,100);
  b1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0000.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0001.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0002.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0003.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0004.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0005.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0006.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0007.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0008.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0009.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0010.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0009.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0008.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0007.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0006.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0005.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0004.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0003.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0002.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0001.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0000.png');
  b1.scale = 0.15;
  
  b1.onMousePressed= function() {
    var bb1 = createSprite(windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2);
    bb1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0000.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0001.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0002.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0003.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0004.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0005.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0006.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0007.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0008.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0009.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0010.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0009.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0008.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0007.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0006.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0005.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0004.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0003.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0002.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0001.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0000.png');
    tint(255,127);
    bb1.scale = 0.4;
  }
  // movingBlocks.add(bb1);
}

function draw() {
  background(240,240,240);
  mouseBlock.position.x = mouseX;
  mouseBlock.position.y = mouseY;
  mouseBlock.scale=0.3;

  // mouseBlock.displace(bb1);
  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: `    for(var i=0; i<allSprites.length;i++){
      var block1 = allSprites[i];
    }
    mouseBlock.displace(block1);` If I add this in the draw function it works, but I can't press the first sprite to let the second one appear. I want the first ones to be static.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it! I needed to change things about the order of my code. The place where I add a sprite to a group had to be relocated and then I could say mouseBlock.displace(movingBlocks);

```
var movingBlocks;
var mouseBlock;
var bb1;
var b1;

function preload() {
  mouseBlock = loadImage('mouse.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  mouseBlock = createSprite(200,200);
  mouseBlock.addAnimation('normal', 'mouse.png');

  movingBlocks = new Group()
  var b1 = createSprite(windowWidth-200,100);
  b1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0000.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0001.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0002.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0003.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0004.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0005.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0006.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0007.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0008.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0009.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0010.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0009.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0008.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0007.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0006.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0005.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0004.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0003.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0002.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0001.png','stamps/static/BB1/1BuildingBlock0000.png');
  b1.scale = 0.15;

  b1.onMousePressed= function() {
    var bb1 = createSprite(windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2);
    bb1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0000.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0001.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0002.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0003.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0004.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0005.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0006.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0007.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0008.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0009.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0010.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0009.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0008.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0007.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0006.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0005.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0004.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0003.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0002.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0001.png','stamps/move/BB1Move/1BBMove0000.png');
    tint(255,127);
    bb1.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb1);
      // mouseBlock.displace(bb1);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(240,240,240);
  mouseBlock.position.x = mouseX;
  mouseBlock.position.y = mouseY;
  mouseBlock.scale=0.3;

    // for(var i=0; i<allSprites.length;i++){
    //   var block1 = allSprites[i];
    // }
    mouseBlock.displace(movingBlocks);

  drawSprites();
}
```